# No module name Pyrebase on Fedora 26

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fedora-26

im actually doing a project where i need to communicate with a database in Python.

So, i decided to use Firebase as its pretty simple to use and im a beginner.

In my code i wrote `import pyrebase` and tried `from pyrebase import pyrebase` but i still have this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./N4S.py", line 4, in 
>       import pyrebase
>   ImportError: No module named pyrebase

My pip is up to date, i tried to install pyrebase and all tools i could found (pyasn1) with both pip and pip3 and it says that its already installed.

Thanks.

Edit : The problem is now solved, i just added `import time` and it suddenly works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to install it from the .whl file ?

Download link:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyrebase/3.0.27

```
sudo pip install "Pyrebase-3.0.27-py3-none-any.whl"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried it and it says "Requirement already satisfied:" for all, and I stil have the "no module named pyrebase" error.